# Handling method signature when parameters vary according to the 1st argument

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, methods, signature

I have the below method in which the arguments to be passed to the method vary according to the value of the ENUM which is passed as the 1st argument.

```
 public void startReporter(ReportType reportType, long period, Class className) {
        reportHandler = new ReportHandler(metricRegistry);
        switch (reportType) {
            case CONSOLE_REPORTER:
                reportHandler.startConsoleReport(period);
                break;
            case SLF4J_REPORTER:
                reportHandler.startSLF4JReport(className,period);
                break;
            case JMX_REPORTER:
                reportHandler.startJMXReport();
        }
    }
```

As you can see, not all the arguments that are passed are used in all cases in the switch statement. What is the best way to address this scenario? I do not want to have 3 methods. I need to do this with only this method. It would be great if the caller of the method can have an idea of this just by looking at the signature.

Comment: Create overloads that will pass `null` for optional parameters when calling the main method.

Comment: Creating overloads is equal to having 3 different methods for calling the reporters without having an Enum isn't it?

Comment: No. Your logic will be still encapsulated in a single method (as it is now) and overloads will be just wrappers for parameter combinations.

Comment: when someone calls 'startReporter' with reportType = JMX_REPORTER, what will be the method call looks like. Is it startReporter(ReportType.JMX_REPORTER, null, null) ??

Comment: Something doesn't smell quite right.  `reportHandler` goes out of scope immediately after you invoke the `start....()` method.  Is the `ReportHandler` object is really ephemeral and not needed? Or, does it have some static side-effects?

Comment: It's actually not clear at all what you want to do.  What about your current code is driving this question?  It might help if you showed how `startReporter` is invoked and what you want the invocation to look like.

Comment: @mayooran Can you show the code inside `ReportHandler`. Also it's not at all clear what you are trying to achieve. What do you mean by "It would be great if the caller of the method can have an idea of this just by looking at the signature?"

Answer (score 0):

> the arguments to be passed to the method vary according to the value of the ENUM which is passed as the 1st argument.

I guess it is because you are mixing construction arguments with method invocation arguments.

The enum is named `Report`**`Type`**. A **type** is usually a class and the arguments you are passing to the method are the constructor arguments for a specific type. I mean you are hiding classes behind the enum.

Take a look at this restructured code and it might be clear what I mean:

```
public void startReporter(ReportType reportType, long period, Class className) {

  // report handler construction
  switch (reportType) {
    case CONSOLE_REPOTER:
      reportHandler = new ConsoleReportHandler(period);
      break;
    case SLF4J_REPORTER:
      reportHandler = new SLF4JReportHandler(className, period);
      break;
    case JMX_REPORTER:
      reportHandler = new JMXReportHandler();
  }

  // report handler invocation
  reportHandler.startReport();
}
```

Concrete types usually have different constructor arguments. So the 'problem' you describe isn't really a problem. But if you don't show me more code (especially the code that uses the method) I can't help you to re-design your code.

Answer (score -1):

I guess it's the shortest way to do so:

1. Use wrapper class in your method signature. 
   `void startReporter(ReportType reportType, Long period, Class className)`
2. If no parameter needed, just send `null` instead 
   Like. 
   `startReporter(reportType, period, null);` 
    `startReporter(reportType, null, null);` 
   `startReporter(reprotType, period, className)`;

Also if `var period` bear un-signed value you may pass -1 instead..